# How to write sorting in more efficient way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project where I have to write an efficient code which will be working as fast as possible, but I have lack of knowledge do to it so...

So I have an asp.net(MVC) project using entity framework and as well I have to use Web Service to get info about details from it.
First I make request to Web service and is responds with a long string, which i have to parse in a list of strings for further activities.

I parse this string like this:

```
string resultString;
char[] delimiterChars = { ',', ':', '"', '}', '{' };
List<string> words = resultString.Split(delimiterChars).ToList();
```

From here i have list with a lot of rows, which have information and a lot of junk rows, which look like this:

[image: list of strings]

I decided to clear this list from junk info, so as not to work with it in further methods and not to check this rows with ifs and so on:

```
for (int i = words.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (words[i] == "" || words[i] == "data" || words[i] == "array") words.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

After this I got clear list, but every decimal number like prices, sizes and so on got separated by `,`, so if I had price 21,55 in my list it now looks like 2 elements 21 and 55. I cant just delete `,` from separators, because string I get as a response from web service mainly separates info by putting `,`.

So I decided to glue decimal numbers back (before this block list elements looked like: 1)attrValue 2)21 3)55  and after like : 1)attrValue 2)21.55):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < words.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (words[i] == "attrValue")
            {
                try
                {
                    var seconPartInt = Int32.Parse(words[i + 2]);
                    words[i + 1] += "." + words[i + 2];
                }
                catch { }
            }
            if (words[i].Contains("\\/")) words[i].Replace("\\/", "/");
        }
```

Every thing is ok, list is sorted, decimals are gathered, but speed is slowed down by 30%. After some tests with stopwatch and commenting blocks of code it became clear that this code above slows down the whole program too much...

To sum up: 
I cant use that slow code and at the same time do not know how to make it work faster. May be the problem is that I convert string to int so as to check whether next element in the list is second part if my number.

How could I optimize my code?

Comment: It looks like to me that you are getting a CSV file from the web service. Do you know if the file is going to be the same every single time? If so I would think about serializing the return with a CSV parser. It would make it easier to manage as objects in my opinion and you can choose to ignore what you don't need by default.

Comment: Why you working on string? You can parse string into objects and work on objects.

Comment: If you continue to use `String.Split`, an easier way to get rid of empty strings is to use the version that takes a `StringSplitOptions` parameter. You should use the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option.

Comment: Use `Int32.TryParse()` instead of `Int32.Parse()`.  Thrown exceptions are very expensive and since your code expects alot of parse failures, you will get a large performance boost if you switch to `TryParse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should do is use this version of `Split` to avoid getting empty entries (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
List<string> words = resultString.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .ToList();
```

Also, if you know that "data" and "array" are in the string and you never want them, replace them with blanks before you split the string.

```
resultString = resultString.Replace("data", String.Empty)
    .Replace("array", String.Empty);
```

What I don't understand is how the comma can be both a field delimiter and a meaningful character, and how you can possibly know the difference (i.e. whether 25,50 should be a single value or two values).

Comment: As for `"how it can be both a field delimiter and a meaningful character"`, I'm not sure but it could be that the culture uses the comma instead of the period as its decimal separator.

Comment: As for how to tell the difference, maybe each actual number is *always* separated by some other text, so that if two numbers are next to each other in the array, they are actually the integer part and fractional part of the same number?

Comment: Yes int and fractional  part are separated by `,` here is example attrValue : {\"data\":{\"array\":[{\"articleAttributes\":{\"array\":[{"attrId\":496,\"attrIsConditional\":false,\"attrName\":\"Iekšējais diametrs [mm]\",\"attrShortName\":\"Iekšējais diametrs\",\"attrUnit\":\"mm\",\"attrValue\":29,05,\"attrValueId\":15235403}